# Filter on numerical values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I would like to filter only on numerical values 0-9 from a list of values that are in VARCHAR format

```
column:postal_Code
dhf65784ja!
s73;'235fsa
(kadf8(*45--

Expected Output
65784
73235
845
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT distinct  
    postal_Code

FROM xx

where 1=1
and postal_Code!~ '[A-Z]' 
and postal_Code!~ '[a-z]' 
and postal_Code!~ '[-_º~@!"./#%£^$]'
```

However this does not give the right output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `regexp_replace`

Example:

```
select regexp_replace(postal_Code, '[^0-9]', '') from xx;
```

Comment: Just for fun, this is the same thing with fewer keystrokes: `regexp_replace(str, '\D')`